# Pythonの正規表現でスペースの後の長音にマッチさせたい

Tags: python, 正規表現

お世話になっております。
表題の通りなのですが、Pythonの正規表現でスペースの後の長音にマッチさせようとしています。
しかし、試しに下記のコードを作ってみたのですが、マッチオブジェクトが何も帰ってこず、うまくいかない状況です。
ちなみに、Notepad++や秀丸エディタ等、他のエディタの正規表現ではうまくマッチでき、「 ー」が選択された状態になります。
正規表現がどこか間違っているのでしょうか。

```
import re
teststring = 'ケ ーキ'
compiled = re.compile(r'\s+ー+')
compiled.match(teststring)
```

環境は、Windows10 64ビット、Python 3.7.9 32ビットです。
何かアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[re.match](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.match)は先頭がマッチするか判定します。
部分一致の場合は[re.search](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.search)を使ってください。

```
compiled.search(teststring)
#<re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match=' ー'>
```

Comment: あああ、そうでした。初歩的なミスでした。ありがとうございました。