# pythonでの正規表現がうまく機能しません。

Tags: python, 正規表現

```
baby_0/0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.9_/qqqb_,
baby_0/0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.6000000000000001_/qqqb_
baby_0/0.02_0.01_0.02_0.2_0.7000000000000001_/qqqb_
...
```

この文字列のリスト`file_names`を正規表現を用いて、

```
0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.9_
0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.6000000000000001_
0.02_0.01_0.02_0.2_0.7000000000000001_
...
```

だけにしたいのです。

```
match_result = [None] * len(file_names)
for i, j in enumerate(file_names):
    match_result[i] = re.match(pattern1, j)
    print(match_result[i])
    print(j)
    match_result[i] = re.match(pattern2, match_result[i])
```

現状、`print(match_result[i])`でNoneとなっており、そのせいで、二回目の正規表現でエラーが主力されます。
どうすれば、いいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub()` を使ってみてはどうでしょうか。

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

file_names = [
  'baby_0/0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.9_/qqqb_',
  'baby_0/0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.6000000000000001_/qqqb_',
  'baby_0/0.02_0.01_0.02_0.2_0.7000000000000001_/qqqb_',
]

filter_result = [re.sub(r'^.*?/(.*)/.*?$', '\\1', fn) for fn in file_names]
pprint(filter_result)

# =>
['0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.9_',
 '0.02_0.01_0.02_0.1_0.6000000000000001_',
 '0.02_0.01_0.02_0.2_0.7000000000000001_']
```

Comment: `\\1`と言うのは、どういう意味なのでしょうか？なぜ、`\\1`と置換後の文字列を置くとうまく行くのかが理解できません。

Comment: `r'^.*?/(.*)/.*?$'` における、`()` で囲まれた部分を指しています(後方参照)。

Comment: 後方参照について調べたのですが、いまいち理解が出来ませんでした。分かりやすいサイトなどはありますか？

Comment: Python の公式ドキュメントの [Regular Expression HOWTO: More Pattern Power - Grouping](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) にある、"Backreferences in a pattern allow you 〜 ... but you’ll soon find out that they’re very useful when performing string substitutions" でしょうかね。簡潔すぎて返って分かりづらいかもしれませんが。

Comment: 正規表現における後方参照に関して、別質問として投稿してみてはどうでしょうか。広く回答を募れば希望に適う資料が見つかるかもしれません。

Comment: わざわざありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

[re.match](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.match)は先頭がマッチするか判定します。
部分一致の場合は[re.search](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.search)を使ってください。

[類似質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/80628/9820)